# How to use GoogleTest/GoogleMock to test a hash table implementation?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, data-structures, googletest, googlemock

I want to write unit tests using **GoogleTest**/**GoogleMock** for a hash table implementation I am writing for practice, but I don't know what the best approach would be.

Here are the hash table interfaces:

### hash_table.h

```cpp
#include <vector>

#include "bucket.h"
#include "node.h"

namespace hash_table {

class HashTable {
 private:
  unsigned int hash_table_size_{0};
  std::unique_ptr<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bucket>>> buckets_;
  [[nodiscard]] auto GetHash(unsigned int value) const -> unsigned int;

 public:
  explicit HashTable(unsigned int size);
  auto Insert(std::unique_ptr<Node> node) -> void;
  auto Remove(unsigned int value) -> bool;
  [[nodiscard]] auto Find(unsigned int value) const
      -> std::variant<Node*, std::tuple<Node*, Node*>>;
  [[nodiscard]] auto GetBuckets() const
      -> std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bucket>>&;
};

}  // namespace hash_table
```

### bucket.h

```cpp
#include "node.h"

namespace hash_table {

class Bucket {
 private:
  std::unique_ptr<Node> first_node_;

 public:
  Bucket();
  auto SetFirstNode(std::unique_ptr<Node> first_node) -> void;
  [[nodiscard]] auto GetFirstNode() const -> Node*;
};

}  // namespace hash_table
```

### node.h

```cpp
#include <memory>

namespace hash_table {

class Node {
 private:
  std::unique_ptr<unsigned int> value_;
  std::unique_ptr<Node> next_node_;

 public:
  Node();
  auto SetValue(std::unique_ptr<unsigned int> value) -> Node&;
  [[nodiscard]] auto GetValue() const -> unsigned int*;
  auto SetNextNode(std::unique_ptr<Node> next_node) -> Node&;
  [[nodiscard]] auto GetNextNode() const -> Node*;
  [[nodiscard]] auto GetNextNodeOwnership() -> std::unique_ptr<Node>;
};

}  // namespace hash_table
```

My intuition tells me that the best approach would be to somehow mock/stub a hash table data structure, and then e.g. run assertions on the `Find` function for different parameter values and check whether the values returned from the mocked hash table match the expected values. This could be done using a parameterized test, but it would require me to use the `Insert` function and `Bucket` and `Node` objects to create such a data structure, which seems like an anti-pattern since it implies that those three elements in the implementation work flawlessly.

Now I'm wondering what the best-practice approach would be.

Here's how far I got with the tests:

```cpp
#include "hash_table.h"

#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>

namespace hash_table {

using TupleReturnType = std::tuple<Node*, Node*>;
using VariantReturnType = std::variant<Node*, TupleReturnType>;

class MockNode : public Node {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD(Node&, SetValue, (std::unique_ptr<unsigned int> value));
  MOCK_METHOD(unsigned int*, GetValue, (), (const));
  MOCK_METHOD(Node&, SetNextNode, (std::unique_ptr<Node> next_node));
  MOCK_METHOD(Node&, GetNextNode, (), (const));
  MOCK_METHOD(std::unique_ptr<Node>, GetNextNodeOwnership, ());
};

class MockBucket : public Bucket {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD(void, SetFirstNode, (std::unique_ptr<Node> first_node));
  MOCK_METHOD(Node*, GetFirstNode, (), (const));
};

class MockHashTable : public HashTable {
 public:
  explicit MockHashTable(unsigned int size) : HashTable(size) {}

  MOCK_METHOD(void, Insert, (std::unique_ptr<Node> node));
  MOCK_METHOD(bool, Remove, (unsigned int value));
  MOCK_METHOD(VariantReturnType, Find, (unsigned int value), (const));
  MOCK_METHOD(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bucket>>&, GetBuckets, (), (const));
};

}  // namespace hash_table
```

Comment: [OT] :`std::unique_ptr<unsigned int> value_;`? won't `unsigned int value_;` do the staff?

Comment: Yeah, I guess you are right. I played with the implementation a lot when I started working on this, and was thinking that I might need to transfer ownership of the value at some point or another, but I never needed that feature anyway and then just forgot about it and forgot to remove the smart pointer. Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: I don't think I'd test the internals of hash map separately. It will turn into `EXPECT_CALL` hell and will make tests brittle, not allowing you to refactor without touching tests (or you will end up reimplementing the internals as mocks/stubs, which is probably even worse). Test the map as a whole, with real buckets and real nodes, and test the API you have accessible.

Comment: Is `Node`/`Bucket`/`hashTable` seems interconnected and not fit to mock IMO, test those as a whole.

Comment: Your interfaces look a bit weird to me, e.g. `Insert(std::unique_ptr<Node> node)` but `Remove(unsigned int value)`. Apart from that, `Node` and `Bucket` seem just like implementation details, so don't touch them. Just test the observable behavior like: "if I insert a `Node` with value x, then `Remove(x)` shall return true".

Comment: @Jarod42 I looked into the implementation now and I used `std::unique_ptr<unsigned int> value_` because I can set `nullptr` values for nodes with no value set. And yes, I guess that testing the hash table as a whole makes the most sense, but still I don't know how to mock it properly